# Frame is not resetting after giving constraint of uiview, iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]Layout constraint is given on story board `top`, `bottomlayoutguide`, `leading` and `trailing` of uiview. At run time i am unable to reset frame. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: include more details about what you wan't to achieve. You can change the frame by altering the `constant` property of AutoLayoutConstraint.

Comment: I have attached screen shot.

Comment: You should not modify directly the `frame` property of a view that has autolayout constriants: the constraints will "fight back" and your view will behave erratically. Instead, modify the value of the constraint's `constant` property.

Comment: Can I modify constant property at run time?

Comment: Check my answer here on how you can change the frame by modifying the constraint. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082458/how-to-shift-a-view-with-animation-with-auto-layout-constraints-are-on-ios/34084364#34084364](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082458/how-to-shift-a-view-with-animation-with-auto-layout-constraints-are-on-ios/34084364#34084364)

Comment: @NazishAli, you can modify constant value runtime. Its read-write property.

Comment: @NazishAli, dont' change frame, change the Constraint, and update your View. It will work.

Comment: thanks to @NicolasMiari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@V S has given the right answer. One can use NSLayout Constraints to change the sizes after allocation. You need to change the constant Value there.

Answer (score 2):

//Add Outlet of Constraint, which you want to change, like Top, Bottom, Height or any.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *vs_constraint_height;
```

//Set Value From Here

```
vs_constraint_height.constant = 50;
```

Thanks.

Happy Coding.